# "File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'User' is not defined" - can't add users to my SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

This is my first question on StackOverflow.

So my mom wants to do math tutoring as a business, and we agreed that I could make the website for aforementioned business. I had the idea of making the website as a Flask web app and then deploying to Heroku, but the site has been annoying enough lately that I'm considering switching to Wix.

Let me explain; I've been following [Pretty Printed's tutorial on how to create a Flask login system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aTnmsDMldY&t=1055s). As of right now, I'm able to go into the Python interpreter, import my database from the app module, and create the table using create_all().

But when I try to create a User object to put into the database, it gives me the error in the title: "User" is not defined.

Furthermore, when I run my Flask app and try to register, it doesn't post the data to the database. The code is supposed to return "Account created - welcome to Numeratory" if the user submits valid data (i.e. if a new user is added to the database), but it just takes me back to the registration form.

I think these errors are related - basically, my user data isn't getting added to the database, and I don't know why. I bet it's right under my nose and I'm just missing it for some reason.

[Here's my code for reference](https://github.com/saimayunus925/numeratory). Thank you all so much!

Comment: have you already created the database siteDB? if ues try to add this siteDB.create_all() in the end of your model.py

Comment: @Loenvpy so you're saying I should put the line "siteDB.create_all()" at the end of my models.py file, correct?

Comment: exactly, or you can put it just bellow the from app_module.models import User in your routes.py file. That way you are creating user table in your siteDB otherwise i think it will not be created

Comment: @Loenvpy I tried that, and it didn't work. Sorry :(